# Calculation of rolling standard deviation by group

Tags: r, grouping, standards, rolling-computation, deviation

I have a long dataset in the following format:

```
Date         Country     Score
1995-01-01   Australia    100
1995-01-02   Australia     99
1995-01-03   Australia     85
:            :             :
:            :             :
2019-06-30   Australia     57
1995-01-01   Austria       67
1995-01-02   Austria       12
1995-01-03   Austria       10
:            :             :
:            :             :
2019-06-30   Austria       21
```

I want to calculate a 90-day period rolling standard deviation of the Score for each country. I have tried using the `rollapply` function (Package:zoo) and `roll_sd` (Package:RcppRoll) but they are not working for groupwise standard deviation. Can anyone please suggest a possible way to calculate the rolling standard deviation.

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout [runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/the_runner_package.html#any-r-function-with-runner)  package and apply any function on rolling windows. Put date into `idx` argument and specify `k = 90` (90-days). Even if you have a gaps in dates it still computer on 90-days instead of 90-elements
- More examples are in [other vignette](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/runner_examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

In general grouping is done separately from the base operation in R so it is not that those functions can't be used for grouped data. It is just that you need to embed them within a grouping operation.  Here we use `ave` to do the grouping and `rollapplyr` to perform the rolling `sd`.

Now, at each point can we assume that the last 90 days are the last 90 rows?  Assuming yes and taking rolling standard deviations of 2 so that we can use the selected rows of the posted data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, 2, sd, fill = NA)
transform(DF, roll = ave(Score, Country, FUN = roll))
```

giving:

```
        Date   Country Score       roll
1 1995-01-01 Australia   100         NA
2 1995-01-02 Australia    99  0.7071068
3 1995-01-03 Australia    85  9.8994949
4 1995-01-01   Austria    67         NA
5 1995-01-02   Austria    12 38.8908730
6 1995-01-03   Austria    10  1.4142136
```

### Wide form approach

Another approach is to convert the data to wide form and then perform the rolling operation:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, split = "Country")
zr <- rollapplyr(z, 2, sd, fill = NA)
zr
```

giving this zoo series:

```
           Australia   Austria
1995-01-01        NA        NA
1995-01-02 0.7071068 38.890873
1995-01-03 9.8994949  1.414214
```

You can then just leave it as a zoo series in order to take advantage of the other time series functions in that package or can convert it back to a data frame using `fortify.zoo(zr)` or `fortify.zoo(zr, melt = TRUE, names = names(DF))` depending on what you need.

### Note

The input used in reproducible form.

```
Lines <- "Date         Country     Score
1995-01-01   Australia    100
1995-01-02   Australia     99
1995-01-03   Australia     85
1995-01-01   Austria       67
1995-01-02   Austria       12
1995-01-03   Austria       10"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
```